# Excel Extracting specific text using getElements

Tags: getelementbyid

New to vba programming and was hoping to get some help on a little program I'm having difficulty with. What I would like for this code to do is extract specific data from an element. So in this example I would like to extract the phone number for each person.

I can get the code to print all of the data in the element, but I only want to extract specified information not everything in the element. Any help would be awesome.

```
    Set Elements = IE.Document.getElementById("member-items").getElementsByTagName("p")

    'Get information
    r = 0
    c = 0
    For Each Element In Elements
        If Element.innerText Like "phone" Then
           Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = Element.innerText
           Debug.Print Element.innerText
           r = r + 1
        End If
    Next Element
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. I did not realize the text is CAP sensitive. So instead of using "phone" I used "Phone" with a CAP "P" and the code worked perfectly. Rockie mistake. =). Hope this helps any other newbies out there. And I used the following code instead:

```
    For Each Element In Elements
        If InStr(Element.innerText, "Phone") Then
           Sheet1.Range("a1").Offset(r, c).Value = Element.innerText
           Debug.Print Element.innerText
           r = r + 1
        End If
    Next Element
```